# is source code for bash sufficient, when I want source code of ext4?

Tags: bash, filesystem, ext4

when I want to know the source code of ext4-filesystem (mkfs.ext4) - is it then sufficient to download the source code for bash ? - or do I need else source-codes after I did :

> sudo apt-get install dkpg-dev

then I did

> sudo apt-get source bash

or is there more to be done ?

Comment: Source of ext4 filesystem code is in Linux kernel source under directory fs/ext4. mkfs.ext4 is only for creating empty ext4 filesystem, and does not handle anything else that filesystem normally does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what `bash` has to do with `ext4`, but the package providing `mkfs.ext4` is `e2fsprogs`:

```
$ dpkg -S `which mkfs.ext4`
e2fsprogs: /sbin/mkfs.ext4
```

To get it, do:

```
apt-get source e2fsprogs
```

Or download the source from [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/e2fsprogs). (The `source` command doesn't need `sudo`.)